# React Native Async Await returns null when called

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous, async-await, expo

I am new to React Native and coming from a PHP background.

***storage.js***

```
const getToken = async () => {
    try {
        return await SecureStore.getItemAsync(authKey);

    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error getting auth token:', error)
    }
}
```

***Client.js***

```
const authToken = async () => await storage.getToken();

console.log('clientjs authtoken -->', authToken());

const apiClient = create({
    baseURL: 'http://www.example.com/mobile',
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + authToken() },
});
```

This console.log shows me this: `clientjs --> {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}`.

I've also simply tried writing: const authToken = storage.getToken(); but getting the same result. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This output does not seem possible. `authToken`, being defined as an `async` function, would always return a promise. Is this your actual code?

Comment: can you please let me know what should be the actual code? I tried this and this also did not work: https://ibb.co/qygwwQ7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `authToken` is marked as an async method, its result needs to be `await`ed or `.then`ed.

```js
const token = await authToken();
const apiClient = create({
    baseURL: 'http://www.example.com/mobile',
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token },
});
```

The above syntax relies on being inside an async method. You can use `.then` in a synchronous context:

```js
let apiClient;

authToken().then(token => {
  apiClient = create({
    baseURL: 'http://www.example.com/mobile',
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token },
  });
});
```

`{"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}` represents an unresolved promise. I wish this was clearer, as it causes a lot of confusion in learning javascript.

Edit: another method to export the client: export a function that returns it.

```js
const getClient = async () => {
  const token = await authToken();
  const apiClient = create({
    baseURL: 'http://www.example.com/mobile',
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token },
  });
  return apiClient;
});

export default getClient;
```

And then in the component:

```js
  getClient.then(client => {
    client.post( // ...
```

Comment: how can I pass this token variable as the Bearer value? define a new global variable `authenticationToken` outside then and pass the value of token to authenticationToken inside then and then use authenticationToken variable inside create? If so, I tried this and it did not work. It says undefined.

Comment: It still has to be awaited in that context. I'll update my answer to include the client creation

Comment: @Abe is correct, you need to wait for the promise results

Comment: https://ibb.co/tZvzY6b I tried this as well but the export is then failing as you can see in the image attached.

Comment: I don't see that anything is failing in the image, are you seeing an error somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, this is the error: ibb.co/9sC0Kcz .
Where it is being consumed, it says its `undefined`

Comment: Can you show how it is imported and consumed?

Comment: This is how I exported in one file and consumed in another: https://ibb.co/WVdWTcg
But because the apiClient is inside then , it is not exporting correctly and hence its undefined where I am consuming?

Comment: No, inside the `then` the variable is modified in the outer scope.  Can you try adding a catch clause, and make sure your getToken request is working? `.catch(error => console.error(error))`

Comment: Get token request is working inside the then but how do I export it?

Comment: I edited the response with another method you can try - returning the client from an async function